# formatting date on insert to sql?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, vb6

I have a VB6 application where I insert a set of dates into a SQL-SERVER. Each time I insert a value, it gets inserted as **1978-12-12 00:00:00.000**. Is it possible to specify in the INSERT statement, how you want the date to be formatted? VB6 does not seem to recognize CONVERT. I did previously CONVERT date when I loaded it into a MSHFlexGrid like this:

```
Convert(varchar,tblClient.DOB, 101)
```

But I did this in a select statement. Will SQL let me insert a value in a format MM/DD/YYYY as I need it later in that format.
The reason why I need the formatting is because I connected all my tables in SQL-SERVER2008 to Access for report generating purposes. So I need it formatted correctly in SQL-SERVER2008 as it dynamically connects to Access.

Comment: You need to format your date in your reports, not in the server backend. Even if you put in the database '1978-12-12' it won't be formatted in the database but just stored as a float value.

Comment: So it will always have a time stamp in the database? The problem is I'm using a datetimepicker in the VB6 application, so I will need to include a where condition specifying date, but that date will be in MM/DD/YYYY format, while the date in access has a time stamp on it as well. Not to sure how to go about this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about VB6, the datetimepickers I use take a "raw" date as input, show it formatted just as I want but output a "raw" date again.

Comment: I'm not sure if/how well Access can handle this (I'm assuming it can), but if you don't need the time component of your `DateTime`, you can change the data type to `Date`  [MSDN Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724(v=sql.100).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, the data type of the column in the database is set to Date or DateTime.  Basically, if you want to store a date, then use a date date type.

That being said, in VB6 you usually have to (at least temporarily) store the date as a string so there is almost always a string to date conversion that happens somewhere.

> Will SQL let me insert a value in a format MM/DD/YYYY

Yes.  But you should not do this.  Instead, you should insert the date with the format "YYYYMMDD".  Notice that there are no delimiters.  The problem with mm/dd/yyyy is that it could accidentally be interpreted as the wrong date.  For example, 1/2/2015 would be interpreted as Feb 1, 2015 if you lived in England, or Jan 2, 2015 if you live in the US.  However, SQL Server will always interpret 20150102 and Jan 2, 2015.

Once you have the data stored the way you want in the database (as an actual date data type), you should actually return it as a date to your front end (either Access or VB6).  In the front end, you should use the format command to display the date.  The format command will use the regional settings of the computer to display dates the way the user wants to see it.

Ex:

```
txtDateOfBirth.Text = Format(rs.Fields.Item("DOB").value, "Short Date")
```

Doing things this way... you should never have problems with dates.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is not to store formatted dates in your database server.

One way you can get what you want is by using a view where you format your data and use that as input for your report:

```
CREATE VIEW myreport
SELECT replace(convert(NVARCHAR, mydate, 106), ' ', '/') from mytable
```

But I would recommend formatting dates on the application level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VB6s format function prep the date before inserting it into SQL.  Here's an example (tested in VBA).

```
Format(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD")
```

Comment: Then you would need to put it into a varchar column instead of a date column. If you want to store dates, please store date, not varchars or integers.

Comment: 100% agree, dates should be stored in a date column.  The format function allows you to pass a VB6 date to a SQL Server date parameter/field.  Of course you could argue it's a hack (strictly speaking you are passing a string which SQL Server can and will parse into a valid date).